# Monitor my database every hour to prevent data loss

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, jobs

Here is my requirement, though I'm aware what could possibly be done to fulfill it but still looking out for the best solution to work out with.

A few days ago someone (some hacker or some previous developer) had truncated my important table causing inconvenience to my customers. I need to change my database password, server's password and other application's password in order to avoid such obnoxious actions and prevent my application.

Additionally first I need to know if this kind of activity is being performed with my data before my customers so that I can find out any work around for them. This is what I thought of:

- I should create a Windows service which will run in every 1 hour and check in all tables or most importantly in main tables that # of records are as expected or not. If not then an alert will be sent to me, so that I can quickly fix that.
- I should create a SQL job which will perform same steps that I mentioned in first point.

These workarounds seems fine and workable. But I'm really curious to know what else can I do to prevent my data or alert me in case of data lost. I'm sure there are other efficient and more feasible way to achieve what I want. It would be great if anyone can help me around.

Comment: Set up a network monitoring tool with which you monitor your database. e. g. PRTG from [Paessler](http://paessler.com) has got a freeware version which could do the job for you. I know its a bit overload to set up a monitoring tool to only monitor a database, but with this tool you could also monitor other things to prevent such a disaster.

Comment: with or without any monitoring tools, you should have regular database backup

Comment: @Squirrel we do have backups everyday, but I can't manually see in every hour that whether my data okay or not. I need to be alerted in case of such disaster so that I can restore the previous backup.

Comment: The first thing which came into my mind was: IMHO you are approaching this from the completely wrong side. You are looking for a technical solution for an organizational problem. If that action was performed by some malicious guy: why does he have write access to the database? Isn't there a restriction on the number of people who even have enough access rights for the DB to perform such actions?

Comment: @DocBrown there are way too smart people to do evil things even after some restrictions, I know that means restrictions need to be more strict, that we'll do for sure. But to be more careful & preventive and avoid customer's inconvenience we want some alert methodology.

Comment: You have assumed that the attacker guessed or knew a password.  But they could just as easily have exploited a security hole in your software.

Comment: @JamesYoungman There is a very high probability that the attacker be a previous developer who already knew the password. Along with changing all passwords I need a foolproof prevention of such attacks.

Comment: Then consider a security audit (and, if they recommend it, an intrusion detection system). After all, if the attacker becomes persistent they could drive your customers away. Truncating the table was fortunately a mild attack. Imagine instead if they had subtly altered pricing or billing data.